# Resolving IP conflicts when connected to an OpenVPN server

Tags: networking, routing, openvpn

I have a home network, which consists of multiple machines in the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet.

My friend also has a home network, which uses the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet.

If I connect to my home network using OpenVPN (tap, not tun) and try to access my machine on (for example) 192.168.1.197, I'm pretty sure my client won't know where to route these packets as the same subnet is used on both networks, and that very IP could be used in both networks too.

How can I reliably fix this problem regardless of wherever I connect to my home VPN from?

Do I have to change my home network to use a different subnet? Or am I supposed use "push route" on OpenVPN? What's the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common complaint.

For a point-to-site connection, where a single workstation is connected to the remote network by VPN, you can make it work, as long as you disable split-tunneling, and force all traffic through the tunnel, which means that you can only use the remote network while connected. Your VPN client will have to have a local virtual adapter, and be configurable such that all traffic is directed into the tunnel. Some clients can be configured this way, but others cannot. By connecting to the remote site, you lose the ability to access the local network. There is no way to have them both accessible at the same time if you have an network Id conflict.

For a Site-to-site connection you cannot fix this problem using standard home networking equipment. The only option available to non-enterprise users without a big budget is to change one of the networks to use another IP. This is why it is a good idea to avoid using common network ids in the 3rd octet when defining /24 networks. in particular avoid .0., .1., .254. etc.

Comment: reviewing the definitions, i see my terminology is not correct. errant  references removed.

Comment: Some information I've read online says that tap could be a problematic (unsure if related to IP conflicts or other problems). Maybe I will just go with tun, since I don't really need the local network.

Comment: the best advice I can give you, is that you will see 192.168.0.0, 192.168.1.0, and 192.168.254.0 on a huge number of /24 networks you may find yourself on when away from home, so if you modify your local network to use a less common network ID (one that isnt a common default OOB for networking gear),  you will likely never experience a conflict again, and if you do, it will be a pretty rare thing. Its generally not too difficult to change your network, especially if you are using DHCP primarily (with reservations as needed). it really is the most reliable and caveat-free solution.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, extremely well known problem, and therefore it has a very proven simple solution. **Renumber one of networks so they don't clash.** This is by far most recommended solution and if you don't have any sufficiently strong circumstances against it (*you* certainly don't), you should take this path.

---

For others who might be interested in other solutions I humbly remember that the main respectable source of information about OpenVPN is [`man openvpn`](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-6/). It lists all the features and how to use them. Reading it you may find an an option `client-nat`, which is basically stateless one-to-one NAT performed by the OpenVPN program. In this case, it makes it look so each one sees other side as some other network. It is very confusing. An example let's add the following:

```
...
push "client-nat snat 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
push "client-nat dnat 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0"
...
```

to this faulty client CCD file on the server. Then, the client will see the server's resource 192.168.1.x under the IP 192.168.2.x.

Use `verb 6` for OpenVPN to explain into its logs what it is doing.

Another way to do this is to run similar NAT in the OS on one side (for example, using Linux's `NETMAP` iptables target or its routing engine stateless NAT feature).
I'll warn again, this is *extremely* confusing and one shouldn't use this unless they are forced to do so with the gun. Each time you run such a config, some innocent kitten suddenly dies somewhere. Don't do this.

Comment: +1 for OpenVPN client-nat. I've not seen that before, but yes using SNAT between the networks has been a traditional solution to this issue, albeit one not usually available to home users.

Answer (score 2):

> If I connect to my home network using OpenVPN (tap, not tun) and try to access my machine on (for example) 192.168.1.197, I'm pretty sure my client won't know where to route these packets as the same subnet is used on both networks, and that very IP could be used in both networks too.

Usually your client *will* "know", kind of, as its routing table has priority set for each of the subnet routes – one of the /24 routes will always have higher priority, usually the VPN route will. So once you connect to the VPN the entire /24 is routed via the VPN.

In other words, it doesn't attempt to know routing on a per-address basis, it only cares about routing the whole subnet at once. (This is similar to being connected to two different 192.168.1.x Ethernet networks; the OS will just always prioritize one over the other.)

This *does* mean that once you've connected to the VPN, you can no longer access a "local" 192.168.1.197 – it will always go to the "VPN" 192.168.1.197 – but often that's acceptable.

[Where problems might occur is if your "local" subnet is smaller than the VPN's (e.g. if the local subnet is a /25 or /26)... but that's just really unlikely to happen for 192.168.x networks.]

> How can I reliably fix this problem regardless of wherever I connect to my home VPN from?

Set up IPv6 on your home network. Not necessarily full ISP-provided IPv6 – just a "local" IPv6 range for internal use within the VPN.

`fd00::/8` is the IPv6 "local" address prefix, similar to the three "local" IPv4 prefixes. But unlike IPv4 where home networks usually pick out out a /24 out of 192.168.0.0/16 (and therefore have only 256 options to choose from), in IPv6 you're supposed to pick out a [randomly generated](https://unique-local-ipv6.com/) /48 from the fd00::/8 – giving you only a 1-in-2<sup>40</sup> chance of collision. And if you randomize the whole /64 (i.e. add a random subnet ID), that extends it to a 1-in-2<sup>56</sup> chance of collision.

So if you played by the rules and actually generated it randomly, your home fdXX/64 will *practically never* conflict with anyone else's fdXX/64 that you may visit. (Of course, don't pick fd00:0:0:0::/64 just because it's easy to type...)

Comment: Great answer. I applaud your comfort with IPv6. many of us, myself included, aren't there yet (which is admittedly ludicrous since i first learned of IPv6 25 years or more ago). I would only point out that the probability of conflict in IPv4 /24 networks is not actually 1:256, but is instead heavily weighted to a small handful of addresses that most device manufacturers have chosen to use as the OOB default. since the distribution is so imbalanced, the probability of conflict plummets to the almost infinitesimal as long as those few common addresses are avoided, even in IPv4.